# Creating Impala external table from a partitioned file structure

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, impala

Provided a partitioned fs structure like the following:

```
logs
└── log_type
    └── 2013
        ├── 07
        │   ├── 28
        │   │   ├── host1
        │   │   │   └── log_file_1.csv
        │   │   └── host2
        │   │       ├── log_file_1.csv
        │   │       └── log_file_2.csv
        │   └── 29
        │       ├── host1
        │       │   └── log_file_1.csv
        │       └── host2
        │           └── log_file_1.csv
        └── 08
```

I've been trying to create an external table in Impala:

```
create external table log_type (
    field1    string,
    field2    string,
    ...
)
row format delimited fields terminated by '|' location '/logs/log_type/2013/08';
```

I wish Impala would recurse into the subdirs and load all the csv files; but no cigar.
No errors are thrown but no data is loaded into the table.

Different globs like `/logs/log_type/2013/08/*/*`  or `/logs/log_type/2013/08/*/*/*` did not work either.

Is there a way to do this?  Or should I restructure the fs - any advice on that?

Answer (score 9):

in case you are still searching for an answer.
You need to register each individual partition manually.

See here for details [Registering External Table](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_tutorial.html#tut_external_partition_data)

Your schema for the table needs to be adjusted

```sql
create external table log_type (
        field1    string,
        field2    string,
...)
  partitioned by (year int, month int, day int, host string)
  row format delimited fields terminated by '|';
```

After you changed your schema, to include year, month, day and host, you recursively have to add **each** partition to the table.

Something like this

```sql
ALTER TABLE log_type ADD PARTITION (year=2013, month=07, day=28, host="host1")
    LOCATION '/logs/log_type/2013/07/28/host1';
```

Afterwards you need to refresh the table in impala.

```sql
invalidate log_type;
refresh log_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this might be to use the `LOAD DATA` function in Impala. If your data is in a SequenceFile or other less Impala-friendly format ([Impala file formats](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_file_formats.html#file_formats)), you can create your external table like Joey does above but instead of `ALTER TABLE`, you can do something like

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/logs/log_type/2013/07/28/host1/log_file_1.csv' INTO TABLE log_type PARTITION (year=2013, month=07, day=28, host=host1);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the newer versions of impala you can use the

```
ALTER TABLE name RECOVER PARTITIONS
```

command. [More info](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_alter_table.html#alter_table)

What you have to be careful about is that, the partitioning fields has to be lowercase as the the directory structure is case sensitive but the impala queries are not.